# Can Hugo convert special characters to a html valid one

Tags: html, hugo

I want to know if there is a configuration in Hugo, that convert automatically all special characters to a html valid one.

For example, if I have this content in my md fle

```
<span>Velásquez</span>
```

I want to my final html look like this

```
<span>Vel&aacute;squez</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your HTML file is defined with `<meta charset="utf-8">`, you don't need extra characters for a valid HTML file.

Did I miss something ?